# VS2019 won't build .asm file even with masm.props build customization enabled?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, masm

I ensured the `masm` build customization is enabled.   I add an `.asm` file to the project.   When I right click and check properties of the `.asm` file it shows blank to include in build (I've also tried saying yes), and the item type as `Microsoft Macro Assembler`.

Now what's weird when I look under the `Microsoft Macro Assembler` section of the configuration properties are all blank.

So I have release / x64 chosen on the toolbar, I choose Tools / Visual Studio Command Prompt.   I enter `ml64` and says not found.  I enter 'ml' and it finds it.   I guess it just opens x86 command prompt even though I have x64 chosen.  So I search for ml64.exe and it's found:

```
Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64

11/15/2023  05:01 AM           592,320 ml64.exe
               1 File(s)        592,320 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64

11/15/2023  05:01 AM           446,448 ml64.exe
               1 File(s)        446,448 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\x64

03/14/2024  01:27 AM           605,784 ml64.exe
               1 File(s)        605,784 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x64

03/14/2024  01:27 AM           457,184 ml64.exe
               1 File(s)        457,184 bytes
```

I checked where it's getting ml.exe from (the x86 version):

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\Tools>where ml
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\ml.exe
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

TIA!!

Comment: Once upon a time I had a problem with VS like this.  Fix was to remove the asm file from the solution, then re-add it.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I tried removing/adding to project, I think I also tried, remove, close, close vs, open it, add it.  Same problem.  But I'm abandoning vs2019 and going back to vs2008 for this EDK2 project because vs2019 is also having some link issues, like saying things not used are not found even with /OPT:REF ...